# I broke .Bind() in Javascript/ReactJs. Not sure how to Fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

import 'materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';
import 'materialize-css/js/materialize.js';
import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
import '../styles/main.scss';

export default class AddStorageModal extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { storageName: "", sharingKey: "" };
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }
    validate() {
        if (this.state.storageName === "" && this.state.sharingKey == "") {
            console.log("validation error");
            return false;
        }
        this.props.createNewStorage(this.state);
    }
    resetForm() {
        this.setState({ storageName: "", sharingKey: "" });
        $(function () {
            Materialize.updateTextFields();
        });
    }
    render() {
        if (this.props.storages.openAddStorageModal) {
            $('#add-new-storage-modal').openModal({ dismissible: false });
        }
        else {
            this.resetForm.bind(this);
            $('#add-new-storage-modal').closeModal();
        }
        return (
            <div id="add-new-storage-modal" className="modal" >
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <h6>Enter your new Storage (Freezer, Pantry, etc.) </h6>
                    <div className="row">
                        <form>
                            <div className="input-field col s12 m12 l12 ">
                                <input id="storage_name" type="text" value={this.state.storageName} name="storageName" onChange={ (event) => this.handleChange(event) } />
                                <label htmlFor="storage_name">Storage Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <h4 className="center">OR</h4>
                            <h6>Enter in the sharing key you were given.</h6>
                            <div className="input-field col s12 m12 l12 ">
                                <input id="sharing_key" type="text"  value={this.state.sharingKey} name="sharingKey" onChange={ (event) => this.handleChange(event) }  />
                                <label htmlFor="sharing_key">Sharking Key</label>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#!" className="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat left" onClick={() => this.validate() }>Add</a>
                    <a href="#!" className="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" onClick={() => this.props.loadAddStorageModal(false) }>Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When "this.resetForm.bind(this);" gets hit, it does not execute it. It use to work but I don't know what I did but now it does not work.

I going to have to work backwards and remove what I did to see if I can figure it out but hoping someone might just know why.

Comment: What exactly were you expecting to happen to call `bind()` on that function at that point? I'm not sure how it's related to react but `Function.prototype.bind()` doesn't actually invoke the function, just returns a new function bound to the new `this` provided and any additional args. Isn't that how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line doesn't do anything anyway. [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) returns a new function, but you're not doing anything with the returned function.

You'll have to be more clear about what you expect that line to do to get a better answer than this. Maybe you just meant to call resetForm like this:

```
this.resetForm( );
```

Comment: I am just trying to get this.restForm to be called. By doing what you suggest will call the method but then it will " this.setState" will fail. Maybe this is just a bad way to go about the whole thing. I am basically trying to make it that every time the modal dialog is open all old inputs are cleared. I could do that in Validate()  but when I actually start saving to a server it might fail to save so I can't just blindly clear the values but at the same time I am not sure how to check if it failed to save as the ajax would happen in my createNewStorage Action.

Comment: @chobo2 If you want to call a function with a specific `thisArg`, you should use call and not bind, EG. `this.resetForm.call( this );` however, in this case `this` is already the calling context if you just do `this.resetForm( );`.

Comment: Good to know, I thought you just put space by mistake. Anyways it is not working(reactjs does not like where I am setting state). So I am just doing it wrong. I going to start a new question to find out best practice for it.

Comment: @chobo2 The space doesn't do anything. It's not a mistake either, just my style. Good luck getting your problem sorted out.